# .htaccess Redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to create a redirect that sends the user to a specified php page with the variable of the page they originally requested, such as:

http://website.com/4

would send them to

http://website.com/download.php?id=4

However I don't want to redirect them if they request an actual page in the root directory, such as website.com/index.php.

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you mean rewrite, instead of redirect? I think so, since that's the answer you accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be exactly what you asked for; rewrites the URL to include `download.php?id=` unless the request is for any file that physically exists already:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ download.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Edit: I added the `RewriteEngine On` because it may not work without it depending on your server setup. To be fair, mlerley's answer reminded me that it should be there.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Apache 2.2:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\d+)$ /download.php?id=$1
```

The url doesn't change in this case.  This also assumes that your id is always a number.